# NullPointer in Flink OperatorChain pushToOperator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am writing a flink application consuming from kafka

```
FlinkKafkaConsumer<MyPojo> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(TOPIC, new MyPojoDes(), prop)
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = new StreamExecutionEnvironment ();
env.addSource(consumer).print();
```

On a high level this application consumes message from kafka topic and prints it. But when I run it i get below exception

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at    org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:577)
> at
> org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
> at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)

I tried debugging into the code and found that there is a serializer variable in OperatorChain class and that is null, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

I figured out while debugging in Deserializer, I was returning null rather than the actuall type information and hence the serializer variable in OperatorChain was null.

```
public TypeInformation<MyPojo> getProducerdType()
{
    //return null
    return TypeInformationOf(MyPojo.class);
}
```